# Blank screen on system configuration in admin panel for Magento

Tags: magento, configuration

We have encountered a problem with our site.

The system > configuration screen only displays the menu, side menu and footer. When we click on side menu option, the screen remains black and the relevant information does not appear. Please see   [this link](http://www.featuredeco.co.uk/media/config_screen.jpg). This is what appears. When we click on any side menu option, the screen is blank

This is causing a major problem as we are unable to access the information for configuring the site.

Kind regards Paul

Comment: Might also be a missing /layouts/xxx.xml file in /design/adminhtml/default/default/layouts/

Answer (score 6):

One issue sometimes forgotten is that after installation of a new module it may be necessary to recompile, that is, if you have enabled compilation in System/Tools/Compilation.
Before recompilation, the entire configuration page may remain blank.

Answer (score 5):

First, flush the cache (**System > Cache Management**).

If this does not resolve your issue, and assuming that you have a staging instance in which to work, you should deactivate all custom modules, adding each back one at a time until you isolate the module(s) involved. Custom modules *should* be found in `app/code/local/*` and in `app/code/community/*`. To do this, turn off config caching in **System > Cache Management** (or be prepared to refresh this screen with every config change). You can deactivate local modules en masse by switching the `<disable_local_modules>` flag to "true" in `app/etc/local.xml`. There is no corresponding feature for community modules. You will need to refresh the System Config view to see if this fixes the problem. If not, revert `app/etc/local.xml`, and then in `app/etc/modules` start changing each community module's `<active>` flag to "false", refreshing the config panel after each, until your issue is resolved. If disabling local modules does work, follow the same process but only for files in the local codePool.

If the above does not work, you will need to diff your core files against a vigin copy of your version of Magento. Core files to diff:

1. `app/code/core/*`
2. `lib/*`
3. `app/design/adminhtml/*`

Also, verify that there are is no `Mage` namespace under `app/code/local` and `app/code/community`. If there is, move it temporarily to rule out its contents as a culprit.

Comment: thank you. the First option you provide has solved the problem.

Comment: @benmarks. Thank u sir. by removing the a folder named with Mage in the path of app/code/community, I am able to see my configuration page again... but what is the cause for this. why the configuratiionpage gets efected if the Mage folder is present at that path???

Comment: @PavanKumar See the include path bootstrapping in [*app/Mage.php* (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/Mage.php#L40)

Answer (score 0):

Problem: in the admin panel, If you go in system->configuration, you find the (content part) page empty (the header, menu and footer are visible).

Before anything check your logs in /var/log/.

Try to refresh all the magento caches (system->manage caches)
If it doesn't work edit /app/etc/local.xml and disable the local modules setting th "disable_local_modules" to true - true.
REMEMBER to "flush magento cache" (system->manage caches) or disable the caching before reloading the system->configuration page or doing any other operation. 
If the message "access denied" appears you don't have enough authorizations for a specific module.
To solve  go to system->permissions.>roles (choose administrators)  and click on "save role" with permission to "all" selected.
In older versions of magento or if you haven't (or can't) rebuild you need to set the system->permissions->roles  (choose administrators) to "custom" and, after selecting everything, save the role.

For a permanent fix (to choose "all/everything") you need to modify the /app/etc/config.xml file and add the users group that is missing.

Its Working For me ....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. End of the story was a magento extension which had a bug, I deactivated it and it worked again.